# Not Applicable XACML policy semantic error

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, xacml3, abac

I'm currently trying to write a simple policy using XACML.
Unfortunately, My XACML engine doesn't seem to be finding the policy applicable for my request.

What I've done is the following :

### Policy :

```
    <Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
    PolicyId="testPolicy-Quota-Storage"
    RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides"
    Version="3.0">
<Target></Target>
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Permit-Quota-Storage">
        <Description>Quota-Storage Rule : request for storage > 2500mb implies
            that if the profile of a user allows it, the storage plan is scaled
            up
        </Description>
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>


                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">premium</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator
                            AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id-qualifier"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:recipient-subject"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false" />
                    </Match>


                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">store</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator
                            AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false" />
                    </Match>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-greater-than">

                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">2500</AttributeValue>

                        <AttributeDesignator
                            AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
                            MustBePresent="false" />

                    </Match>

                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>

    </Rule>
    <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-1">
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">fixed</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator
                            AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id-qualifier"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:recipient-subject"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false" />
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>

        </Target>
    </Rule>

</Policy>
```

### Request :

```
 <xacml-ctx:Request ReturnPolicyIdList="false" CombinedDecision="false" xmlns:xacml-ctx="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">2500</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">store</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:recipient-subject" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id-qualifier" IncludeInResult="false">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">fixed</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">alice@company.com</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
</xacml-ctx:Request>
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your policy using:

- Axiomatics Policy Administration Point
- A standard XML schema validator plugin via Notepad++

### Validation Errors

In both instances, the validation came back with validation errors:

> ERROR: Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17}Rule':
>   This element is not expected. Expected is one of (
>   {urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17}Description,
>   {urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17}PolicyIssuer,
>   {urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17}PolicyDefaults,
>   {urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17}Target ).

The policy you wrote is not valid XACML 3.0. If you wrote the policy by hand you are missing a few elements. If you wrote the policy with a tool, I suggest you change tools. Use the ALFA plugin for Eclipse for instance. Writing policies with it is easy. [See here](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-applications/developer-tools-and-apis/192-axiomatics-language-for-authorization-alfa.html). It's free for non-commercial use.

I fixed your policy to add the missing elements. I ran another validation and got

> ERROR: Element
>   '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17}Match': This element
>   is not expected. Expected is (
>   {urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17}AnyOf ).

This means your target in rule `Deny-1` is not valid either. You are missing the AllOf/AnyOf elements around the Match element.

### The Policy Inside the Axiomatics PAP

Once I fixed these 2 errors, I could import the policy inside the Axiomatics PAP. Once imported, the UI displays your policy as follows:

[image: Axiomatics Policy Administration Point]

### Simulating the request against the policy

I then ran your request against the policy

[image: The XACML request inside the Axiomatics PAP Simulator]

I can already see that your request is in fact a Multiple Decision request as described in this [blog post](http://www.axiomatics.com/blog/entry/authoring-multiple-decision-profile-requests-2.html). You probably did not intend to create such a request but rather a request with multiple subject attributes. The request should therefore be

```
<xacml-ctx:Request ReturnPolicyIdList="false" CombinedDecision="false" xmlns:xacml-ctx="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">2600</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">store</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
   <xacml-ctx:Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" >
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id-qualifier" IncludeInResult="false">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">premium</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
      <xacml-ctx:Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <xacml-ctx:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">alice@company.com</xacml-ctx:AttributeValue>
      </xacml-ctx:Attribute>
   </xacml-ctx:Attributes>
</xacml-ctx:Request>
```

Now the result of the evaluation is still **NotApplicable** as you noted yourself. The reason is that you did not normalize your values. For instance your request uses `premium` but your policy uses `premium(whitespace)`. The whitespace matters.

Finally once this error has been fixed, you get **NotApplicable** because you simply did not send the right values in e.g. premium and 2500. You can see the evaluation trace in this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: its a greater than fonction so using 2600 should be okey, but my engine still gives NotApplicable, the wso2 identity manager that i just installed however is giving me deny for a deny request. But not applicable for a Permit one.. i updated my main post with the one currently used.

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: WSO2 IS uses Balana so you shouldn't notice any difference in behavior. Try another engine e.g. Heras AF, SunXACML or Axiomatics.

Comment: Well, Axiomatics is not a freeware, SunXacml i snot compliant with xacml 3..
Heras is not compatible with my app right now, so ... I 'll see what I can do..

Comment: Balana is not XACML 3.0 compliant either (partial XACML 3.0 and very buggy at that). Try AT&T then. Oh and there is no free lunch

Comment: We use what we have :) Unlimited budget are not available in every country :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89885/discussion-between-david-brossard-and-sasuke256).